# If an answer is given but I can't check if it is correct or not

Tags: support, accepted-answer, new-users

What to do with acceptance?

The answer may be an url or document and I have to study it first as it is going over my head.

Can I leave it alone for an unkown period and accept an answer when I understand?

EDIT: Without putting a bounty on it, a questions stays unanswered for an infinity length of time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would simply leave a comment thanking the answerer and letting him/her know that you are going to report back once you've taken a look at the resource.

Comment: IIRC, question askers can comment on any answer to their questions.  That might not even be necessary.

Comment: +1 from me - don't feel forced to accept an answer until your comfortable that it actually answers your question =)